# How to get split host details by extending new API of FileInputFormat?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

Hi I am trying to create custom loader for pig by extending `org.apache.pig.LoadFunc` and it requires to implement

```
public abstract org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat getInputFormat() throws java.io.IOException;
```

Now above format `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat` is new API so I have to create custom file format by extending `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat` I have created custom file format using new API but I need to figure out split hosts details using the following code

```
String[] splitHosts = getSplitHosts(blkLocations, 0, length, clusterMap);
```

getSplitHosts() is available in older API `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat` but it is not available in `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat`

My question is how do I figure out getSplitHosts() using new API of `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat`

Please guide I am new to Hadoop thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop 2 is having backward compatiblity and old api still you can use and it is available in new version as well. There will be no problems.
So you can use that class as given in the Hadoop 2.6 version api [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html#getSplitHosts(org.apache.hadoop.fs.BlockLocation[],%20long,%20long,%20org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology))

Hope it helps!